# Spring Data JPA: persist a nested object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a USER(id, role_id, first, last) object, which contains a ROLE(id, role_name) object. ROLE are predefined in the DB, the data looks like: 0, user; 1, admin; 3 superadmin... What is the best way to persist (save) a USER and add role_id to the user based on the role_name? When creating the user, I know the role_name, but not the role id. Do I need to query the role id first then add it to the USER object? I am sure there is a smarter way to do it in Spring Data JPA. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have repositories configured, right?

Assuming you have `RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>` interface you can define method `Role findByRoleName(String roleName)` and fetch `Role` object, attach it to newly created `User` object and persist that user via user repository.
Of course, you have to have valid relationship in `User` class, let's say `@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="user") private Set<Role> roles`.
`cascade` annotation property is configurable of course.

Even better would be if you'd load all roles at application startup in memory since you have them predefined, store them into `Map` and fetch from map when needed.